# Git status reports incorrect information

Tags: linux, git

I had a weird issue where an entire directory in my live CRM project was corrupted after resolving some conflicts from a merge (pull) and some reverts in this live working tree clone.

*Config Overview*:

Bare repo on testing server at `/git/project.git` this is origin master

Publicly accessible testing branch at `/var/www/html/project/httpdocs` which is automatically updated when you `push origin` from local using `/git/project.git/hooks` shell scripts.

Publicly accessible live version at `/var/www/html/project/httpdocs` on another server which I pull manually to; I never push anything from here.

*Issue*:

I had to manually copy over a local copy of the directory to get the live application working again. I ended up doing a `git reset --hard <sha1>` on the testing working tree back to the commit I wanted to be at (because the several commits after that were just totally janked), and a `git update-ref  refs/heads/master <sha1>` to revert my `origin`, a bare public repository, back to the same commit.

I'm just going to delete and re-clone the live branch because I don't care about commit history there and it seems to be a bit jacked up.

Even though I have reset both the bare repo origin master AND the testing working tree back to the same commit -- when I run git status on the testing working tree it says my branch is behind origin/master by 4 commits.

If I try to pull origin master or push origin master it says `everything is up to date`.

What the deal?

Comment: Use `git log master..origin/master` or `gitk master origin/master` to see the commits that it thinks you're behind by.

Comment: Look inside .git/refs/remotes. I think your repository have broken 'remotes' branches.